# Booting openSuse from USB on ASUS T100

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios, opensuse

I tried to install an openSuse 32/64 OS on an Asus Transformer Book T100TA.

I followed the steps on this [site](http://liliputing.com/2013/10/booting-ubuntu-asus-transformer-book-t100.html). If I select the USB device to boot, the BIOS closed and reopened immediately. A similar behavior was described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/873312/booting-from-usb-with-uefi-bios-to-install-windows-8-1).

I have installed openSuse using unetbootin on a 16 GB USB fat32 formatted stick. I have updated the BIOS to the newest version offered by Asus for this device (Version 213, GOP 7.1.1005, EC G1BT1406).

BIOS setup:

- Secure Boot Support: Disabled
- USB Controller Select: XHCI

If I choose `launch EFI shell from filesystem device` I received the message: `not found`.

Can anyone give me some tips?

Thank you,
Alex